# Vuetify 2.6 coloring h1 item using SCSS produces invalid CSS

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have a working build where I can override various Vuetify defaults using variables.scss. This definition is merged properly:

```
$headings: (
        'h1': (
                'size': 40px,
                'line-height': 1.15em,
        ),
);
```

However, if I add a 'color' property like this:

```
$headings: (
        'h1': (
                'color': red,
                'size': 40px,
                'line-height': 1.15em,
        ),
);
```

I get the following mess:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you try it without size in there, and just do color and line-height? Also, is size the right property? What happens if you change it to font-size?

Comment: It does the same mess if I change size to font-size. It seems there are some known properties and you are only allowed to use those. Everything else is mishandled like this.